# Program fixed functions that does not need to be initialized

Tags: vb.net

I have written a function to extract a recieved token from a "xx":"..." format

```
Public Class HelperFunctions
    Public Function ExtractToken(ByVal myToken As String) As String
        'Split fields on comma
        Dim fields = myToken.Split(":")
        'Quote literal
        Dim quote = """"c
        'Use trim to remove quotes
        Dim value = fields(2).Trim(quote)
        Return value
    End Function
End Class
```

But instead of initializing the function

```
Dim hc as New HelperFunctions
hc.ExtractToken(_string)
```

I want to use it straight forward

```
HelperFunctions.ExtractToken(_string)
```

I have not programmed for a while and cannot figure it out as well as come up with the name of this type of functions to find a tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the Function as `Shared`:

```
Public Class HelperFunctions
    Public Shared Function ExtractToken(ByVal myToken As String) As String
        'Split fields on comma
        Dim fields = myToken.Split(":")
        'Quote literal
        Dim quote = """"c
        'Use trim to remove quotes
        Dim value = fields(2).Trim(quote)
        Return value
    End Function
End Class
```

Or as @jmcilhinney said, you can use Module and you don't need to use `Shared` in the methods inside it (also you can't create an instance of an object from a Module):

```
Public Module HelperFunctions
    Public Function ExtractToken(ByVal myToken As String) As String
        'Split fields on comma
        Dim fields = myToken.Split(":")
        'Quote literal
        Dim quote = """"c
        'Use trim to remove quotes
        Dim value = fields(2).Trim(quote)
        Return value
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Or use a Module instead of a Class.